# Mocked class recognized as 'static member' is being called but it is not being recognized in the test as the mock?

Tags: java, mockito

I've mocked the class and it is till giving me this error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I get the error: `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'` on the line that contains

```
Mockito.when(trdi.strToInteger(newValueIn)).thenReturn(0);
```

The class is mocked, but I don't understand why it's giving me this error. My IDE is also telling me that trdi.strToInteger is a static member being accessed via instance reference.

```
public class TestApproved extends TestGroovy {

    @Mock
    private DataLayer dl;
    @Mock
    private DataStore dsIn;
    @Mock
    private DataStore ds;
    @Mock
    private TRDIUtils trdi;

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public String client;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
    public static Object[] data() {
        return new Object[]{
          1, 2, 3, 4
        };
    }

    private String newValueIn;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //groovy script file to test
        groovyScriptFile = new File(GROOVY_SCRIPTS_FOLDER + "/" + client + "/ToTest.groovy");

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        newValueIn = "1";

        //groovy script parameters
        addGroovyBindingVariable(GroovyScriptArgName.DATASTORE, dsIn);
        addGroovyBindingVariable(GroovyScriptArgName.NEW_VALUE, newValueIn);
    }

    /**
     * Test that user and date are nullified/disallowed to be updated if 'Approved' column is unchecked
     *
     */
    @Test
    public void testUncheckedApproved() throws Exception{
        Mockito.when(trdi.strToInteger(newValueIn)).thenReturn(0);

        evaluate();
        Mockito.verify(dsIn, Mockito.times(1)).setItemNull(1,"XX_APPROV_DATE");
        Mockito.verify(dsIn, Mockito.times(1)).setItemNull(1,"XX_APPROV_USER");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mocking static classes we need to use PowerMockito.

Use the following call to prepare you static class methods for mocking

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(TRDIUtils.class)
```

Then start using your methods as the following

```
PowerMockito.when(TRDIUtilsstrToInteger(newValueIn)).thenReturn(0);
```

Hope this helps to customise it for your own logic. Happy coding.

Comment: Just remember that static mocking is a code smell. In many cases, the better solution is to refactor the call so that you do not need static mocking.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz can you elaborate a bit more? I'm fairly new to java and Mockito.

Comment: One of the requirements of good code is that it is easily testable. How good can code be, if you cannot be sure it works and you cannot refactor it because you cannot be sure not to break functionality? So, if your tests become complex and require heavy tools to test (like PowerMock, etc.), it's a "code smell", a sign that this code could be bad. In your case, you have a static method that is complex enough that you need to mock it - which is bad. The most easy solution would be to make it non-static. But of course, to know more, we would need to see the method itself.